# How to fix my NexJs deployment error on Vercel "No serverless pages were built"

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, node-modules, vercel

I'm getting this error in my log when I try to deploy on vercel

```
Found next.config.js:
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: [{ loader: '@svgr/webpack', options: { icon: true } }],
    })
    return config
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
Error: No serverless pages were built. Learn More: https://err.sh/vercel/vercel/now-next-no-serverless-pages-built
```

I've tried deleting the node modules but that does not seem to work
Please help!

Comment: This error is from the vercel log

Comment: What Next.js version are you on? Have you tried following the steps in the link from the error message: https://err.sh/vercel/vercel/now-next-no-serverless-pages-built?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to settings of your project in Vercel dashboard

> [https://vercel.com/[username]/[project]/settings](https://vercel.com/%5Busername%5D/%5Bproject%5D/settings)

#### Follow this process to fix:

1. Scroll down to **Node.js Version** of Search for **Node.js Version** on the page
2. Select a newer version, probably **16x** or **18x** and not 14x
3. Click the 'SAVE' button
4. Navigate back to **Deployments** [https://vercel.com/[username]/[project]/deployments](https://vercel.com/%5Busername%5D/%5Bproject%5D/deployments)
5. Click the hamburger menu (three dots) in your most recent commit
6. Then click the 'REDEPLOY' button and make sure not to select the cache option

App should build successfully now